# Files being listed as being prefixed with ../ in git

Tags: git, windows-7

I've a problem: when I run `git status` from a directory it is listing many files of this directory as `../../../file` which is actually the file without any parent folder prefix in my current directory.

The repo is in D:/.git and my current directory is `/d/anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts` and I use git-bash command shell.  Mine is git 1.8.3.msysgit.o version.

I've never added files in this way. What could be causing this? [image]

Here is the text version I'm pasting( as seen in above image):

```
> D14@D14-PC /d/anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts (master)
> $ git commit
> # On branch master
> # Changes not staged for commit:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> #
> #       modified:   ../../../../../Anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts/copy-site-files.pl
> #       modified:   ../../../../../Anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts/local-common.pl
> #       modified:   backup-gij.pl
> #       modified:   backup-joi.pl
> #       modified:   backup-nav.pl
> #       modified:   backupall.sh
> #       modified:   restoreall.sh
> #
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> #       ../../../../../.gitignore
> #       ../../../../../5632_20269334_MVM_7.tmp
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/admissioncourses.com/
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/govtjobsindia/
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/indiadiscountoffers.com/
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/jobsopeningindia.com/
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/sources/bookrailticket/.buildpath
> #       ../../../../../Anurag/work/sources/bookrailticket/.cvsignore
```

The current directory from which I ran this command is  `/d/anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts` and contains these modified files( as indicated in my Windows 7 Explorer(using TortoiseGit):

[image]

Comment: looks like you initialized repo in your user.home directory

Comment: Please disable colours for the next screenshot, or at least choose a colour scheme with more contrast. Dark red on black is barely visible (at least on my screen).

Comment: even better: simply copy'n'paste the text, rather than creating a screenshot.

Comment: And please ensure that all the details are present. The current directory and the command you ran are nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @Tala the repo is in D:\.git on Windows 7

Comment: @Marco I've made the corrections in the post

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I've made the corrections in the post

Comment: @user5858 so this shows you path from your git repo as expected.

Comment: you most likely are experiencing problems with case-sensitive filenames. you git index has a referenece to `Anurag/work/...` whereas you are now working in `anurag/work/...`; *windows7*/*ntfs* might not be case-sensitive, but `git-sh` (being ported from linux) certainly is.

Answer (score 1):

running `git status` will give you information on the files in the *entire repository*, not just the path you are currently in. the paths will always be shown relative to your current directory, so if you are not in the root of the repo, you will end up with a numboer f `../`

e.g. checking the status from the repository root:

```
$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   bar/knardel.c
#   modified:   baz/README.txt
#   modified:   foo/breslow.xml
#
```

but checking the status from the subdirectory `bar/` will give you:

```
$ cd bar
$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   knardel.c
#   modified:   ../baz/README.txt
#   modified:   ../foo/breslow.xml
#
```

if you only want to see the status of the current subdirectory and it's childs, you can give the current directory (`.`) as the `<pathspec>`:

```
$ git status .
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   knardel.c
#
```

Comment: I've mentioned already that I'm giving command from dir gij-sync-scripts at the same time it is showing the file in it as  ../../../../../Anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts/copy-site-files.pl . That means I'm running the command from the same directory where the file is

Comment: you could make this clearer in your question. there are many questions from non-native english speakers on [so], so i consider a simple *this directory* not the equivalent of the *current working directory*.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing lower and Upper case filenames.
while for windows the paths `D:\Anurag\work\sources\webhosting\gij-sync-scripts` and `D:\anurag\work\sources\webhosting\gij-sync-scripts` might be the same, `git` (coming from the un*x world, where filesystems are usually case sensitive), distinguishes between `/d/Anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts` and `/d/anurag/work/sources/webhosting/gij-sync-scripts`

you can configure git (>=1.5.6) to ignore cases using the `core.ignorecase` option:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

Comment: Isn't this a simple issue of not having run the `git init` in the proper directory? (instead the op seems to have run it for the entire drive)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist i don't know what content the OP wants to track. in general i cannot really see a problem with with tracking an entire "drive" (though i probably wouldn't do it myself)

Comment: That was my thought too. I'm pretty sure it's the `anurag` vs `Anurag` that is causing this.

Comment: The `ignorecase` looks a quicker and cleaner fix.

Comment: Mine is 1.8.3.msysgit.0 ... I've also set the ignorecase as suggestion. But no affect.

Comment: i guess the case-sensitive filenames are still in the index. try committing them first, and see whether the problem persists.

Comment: @umläute I've committed in those (including those with prefix ..). Now when I change a file it is again showing ../../ for this modified, unstaged file. One good thing is that at least ../../ is committing the same file so I'll use ../../ etc for files it forces me to otherwise I'll use simple file name.